# Create a new column using datetime index

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new column with value 1 if the datetme index is less than some date and zero if it is greater. I tried the following code but it doesn't work as intended (the first four days are not encoded with 1).

```
datetime_index = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({}, index=datetime_index)
df['Vacation'] = np.where((df.index >= '2018-01-04') & (df.index <= '2018-01-04'), 1, 0)
df
```

Comment: Your condition is that `(df.index >= '2018-01-04' ) & (df.index <= '2018-01-04')`. The only way that condition can be met is if `df.index == '2018-01-04'`. So the result you get is exactly what you would expect.

Comment: I think I was not clear in the question. Now edited it. I basically want to create a value 1 if the date is less than Jan 4th and zero if not.

Comment: Right. So you just need `(df.index <= '2018-01-04')`. You were combining two different tests with an 'and'.